# I get an System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException error

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error

I got this code in vb.net

```
    Imports RasterEdge.Imaging.Basic.TextSearch
    Imports RasterEdge.XDoc.PDF




    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Open a document
    Dim doc As PDFDocument = New PDFDocument(Application.StartupPath & "/Vertrag.pdf")

    'Set the search options
    Dim options As RESearchOption = New RESearchOption()
    options.IgnoreCase = False
    options.WholeWord = False

    'Replace "RasterEdge" with "Image"
    doc.Replace("#Name", "#Lame", options)   <-- Here i get the error
    doc.Save(Application.StartupPath & "/testoutput.pdf")


    End Sub
    End Class
```

I marked where the **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException** error pops up.

All of this uses the RasterEdge dlls to replace a piece of text with soe other piece of text (#Name **-->** #Lame (just a test))

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: You need to tell us _what the error says_ as well. There is an _**infinite**_ amount of `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` variants. The exact error message is determined by the programmer of the library.

Comment: It says: the index was out of the "specified area". It can't be negative or smaller than the connection.     translated from German

Comment: Hmm... Must be an internal bug in the library seeing as you don't pass any numeric values.